# VBA solution for 'stacking' columns

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a snippet of the table I'm working with.

From left to write I need to know how I can the entire second column appended to the first one.  So, starting at V5789 of the second column, that and all of the contents below it need to be placed after the V854 in the first column.  The third column needs to be 'stacked'onto the bottom of the second one. So 2 appends to 1, 3 appends to 2, 4 appends to 3.  etc.

Any clues?

[image]

Comment: Is this meant to be recursive or do you just need each column appended to the others (i.e., col8 moved to col7 moved to col6... moved to col1, or col8 copied to col7, col7 and col8 copied to col6, etc.)?

Comment: I need all columns appended in order to the first.  No other moving around, Just 2 onto 1, 3 onto 1, 4 onto 1..etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack multiple columns into two colums in pairs of two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613908/stack-multiple-columns-into-two-colums-in-pairs-of-two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DoooooooooIT()

    Dim col As Range, _
        found As Range
    Dim currRow As Integer

    currRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("", after:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext).Row

    For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
      If col.Column <> 1 Then
        Set found = col.EntireColumn.Find("", after:=col.Cells(1, 1), lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        Set found = ActiveSheet.Range(col.Cells(1, 1), found)
        found.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow, 1).PasteSpecial
        currRow = currRow + found.Cells.Count - 1
      End If
    Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently I'm not famous enough to add a comment on your post OP, however, I guess we all need to know whether you're familiar with VBA at all? Do you know how to put either of these answers into a standard module?

Comment: +1 This works, but I would avoid using `Copy` `Paste`, since data transits via the clipboard and other applications can interfere with this, with funny results at both ends. Instead, say `found.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow, 1)`. This doesn't use the clipboard.

Comment: Personally I feel the routine name mitigates this downfall considerably. But seriously, thanks for the tip :).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Danka, gracias, merci or thanks, wherever you're from :).

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 6):

Hows this for an alternative? Only has 2 calls to the worksheet and one loop.

```
Sub append()
Dim g, newArray
Dim strJoin As String
Dim x As Integer

g = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value

For x = 1 To UBound(g, 2)
    strJoin = strJoin & Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(g, 0, x)), "~/"), "/~", "")
    If Right(strJoin, 2) <> "~/" And x <> UBound(g, 2) Then strJoin = strJoin & "~/"
Next x

    newArray = Split(strJoin, "~/")

    Columns(1).Cells(1).Resize(UBound(newArray) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(newArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Quite clever and way faster than the other answers here, though this will obviously fail when cells contain the string `~/` or whatever else you choose as your delimiter! Given enough data input by enough monkeys (or clueless users), this *will* happen.

Comment: haha yes, that's true I felt that ~/ would be a pretty unlikely combination though ;)

Comment: very nice :)  and yes @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, never estimate user ineptitude :)

Comment: You could use a non-printing character, chr(0) is one I sometimes use in similar scenarios, though normally not when the user is allowed to enter any character. Of course, that's not entirely foolproof, just (hopefully) even less likely.

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613908/stack-multiple-columns-into-two-colums-in-pairs-of-two the variant should be tested to see if it is more than 1 cell. I normally use "||" as a delimiter as I think 2 characters is more robust than 1, I like mkingston's idea. +1 btw

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this by using 2 for loops: outer loop will start your counting variable at 2, then iterate up with a step of 1.  This is iterating through your columns.

in that loop, have a nested for loop that iterates through each row of the unique columns.  It will iterate from row one and down, checking each loop if the cell at the position given by the outer loop's column and inner loop's row has anything in it (so check if cell.value = "").  Once it finds the first empty cell in that column, have it copy everything from row 3 until the row counting variable in the outer loop's column and paste it into the previous column at row 3.

I have provided pseudo-code instead of the actual code because I don't believe this would be too difficult to write yourself and I don't have time to at this moment, so you may be able to do it sooner than I will have a chance too.  However, if you want further assistance let me know and I can work on some code for you when I have a chance.

edit: forgot to add, make sure to include something to deal with the unique position of where the second column data needs to go into the first column.  likely best if you just include something like "if PasteToColumn = 1 then paste into cell A9" or something similar

**EDIT again**: here's my new and improved version! let me know what you think/if it works

```
Sub MoveStuff()

Dim rowcounter As Integer
Dim columncounter As Integer
rowcounter = 1
columncounter = 2

Do While Cells(rowcounter, columncounter).Value <> ""
    Do While Cells(rowcounter, columncounter).Value <> ""
        rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
    Loop
    Range(Cells(3, columncounter), Cells(rowcounter - 1, columncounter)).Cut (Columns(columncounter - 1).End(xlDown).Offset(rowoffset:=1))
    columncounter = columncounter + 1
    rowcounter = 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in VBScript honestly.  I added the tag because I was working with data that were in Excel to start off with.  I'll poke around at it as best I can, but any help would be greatly appreciated :) gracias

Comment: well this is VBA, not VBScript.  they are completely different things.  I will get back to you with some code snippets though :)

Comment: @DarrinCecil I updated the answer with some code! let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Just tested it and it doesn't work... Cell contents don't get moved to the right places. Also if you read VBA help on `Range` you will see that your `ConvertToLetter` function is quite unnecessary!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Thanks for pointing that out.  I can't believe I've never thought to use cells inside the range to select a range like that!  However, I have no idea why it didn't work for either of you... what version of excel are you on? it worked for me last night AND works right now in 2007.

Comment: @DarrinCecil I updated my code to work better (I hope).  If you decide to try it let me know if it works for you!