# Stacking blocks of columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to stack a multiple columns in blocks of ten. I saw this example where the stacking is done by pairs of two:

[Stack multiple columns into two colums in pairs of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613908/stack-multiple-columns-into-two-colums-in-pairs-of-two)

Nonetheless, I have not succeeded in modifying it in such a way that columns are stacked in groups of ten.

The original data looks like this:

```
  A  B  C … J   K  L   M ... N T
```

1      1.1  1.2     1.3     …   1.10    1.1 1.2 1.3 …   1.10

2   2.1 2.2 2.3 …   2.10    2.1 2.2 2.3 …   2.10

3   3.1 3.2 3.3 …   3.10    3.1 3.2 3.3 …   3.10

4   4.1 4.2 4.3 …   4.10    4.1 4.2 4.3 …   4.10

5   5.1 5.2 5.3 …   5.10    5.1 5.2 5.3 …   5.10

6   6.1 6.2 6.3 …   6.10    6.1 6.2 6.3 …   6.10

7   7.1 7.2 7.3 …   7.10    7.1 7.2 7.3 …   7.10

8   8.1 8.2 8.3 …   8.10    8.1 8.2 8.3 …   8.10

What I would like to get is this:

```
A   B   C   …   J
```

1   1.1 1.2 1.3 …   1.10

2   2.1 2.2 2.3 …   2.10

3   3.1 3.2 3.3 …   3.10

4   4.1 4.2 4.3 …   4.10

5   5.1 5.2 5.3 …   5.10

6   6.1 6.2 6.3 …   6.10

7   7.1 7.2 7.3 …   7.10

8   8.1 8.2 8.3 …   8.10

9   1.1 1.2 1.3 …   1.10

10  2.1 2.2 2.3 …   2.10

11  3.1 3.2 3.3 …   3.10

12  4.1 4.2 4.3 …   4.10

13  5.1 5.2 5.3 …   5.10

14  6.1 6.2 6.3 …   6.10

15  7.1 7.2 7.3 …   7.10

16  8.1 8.2 8.3 …   8.10

Any hint on a how to do it with the macro mentioned above or another one?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you want a macro that will take all the data in columns K-T and paste it at the bottom of the data in column A-J?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, since it's just the one range you're trying to copy, K:T, you shouldn't have to do any sort of loops in it. Just a straight copy paste should work.

```
Sub MoveData()

    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    Dim lr      As Long
    Dim lc      As Integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lc = ws.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column '' Find the last column

    While lc <> 10 '' stop once it hits Column J
        lr = ws.Cells(1, lc).End(xlDown).Row '' Find the last row for this block of 10
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc).Offset(, -9), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '' Get the entire range for this block of 10, and copy it to the bottom column A
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc).Offset(, -9), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).ClearContents '' Clear it out
        lc = ws.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column '' Get the last column again for the While loop
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: _Thanks, for the prompt answer. Nonetheless, I am wondering if there is a way to extend this to several blocks of ten columns, rather to a single one_

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I'll edit my answer to do that.

Comment: I've edited it, this will work for an infinite numbers of blocks of 10 all with variable row numbers.

Comment: _Thanks for the code and the notes on it, very helpful_