# VBA to stack to several columns under the first two

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I have several workbooks, which contain a lot of columns (each time different number of columns) and a lot of rows. I would like copy all values from range of columns to the columns A and B. The values must be copied pairwise and can contain empty cells and even empty rows, which must be copied as well.

Now I have following structure of the data set:

```
 A    B      C     D      E     F   .......
 red cat   black  dog   yellow fox  .......
 red cat   white  dog   yellow fox  .......
 grey cat  black  dog   yellow fox  .......
 ..........................................
```

After concatenation my data have to look like this:

```
 A       B     
 red    cat   
 red    cat  
 grey   cat
 black  dog 
 white  dog
 black  dog
 yellow fox
 yellow fox
 yellow fox
```

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613908/stack-multiple-columns-into-two-colums-in-pairs-of-two) on stackoverflow, which works fine, but it does not keep the original pairwise order of my data and skips empty cells. It was difficult to me to figure out how to adjust this code to my problem.

Besides, I've found [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604872/stacking-blocks-of-columns-in-excel) and I've tried to modify it, but I get the message "Runtime error 1004" in the line 8.

Here is my modified solution:

```
Sub MoveColumnsUnderAB()

Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim lr      As Long
Dim lc      As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lc = ws.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).column '' Find the last column

While lc <> 2 '' stop once it hits Column B

    lr = ws.Cells(1, lc).End(xlDown).Row '' Find the last row for this block of 2
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc).Offset(, -1), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc).Offset(, -1), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).ClearContents '' Clear it out
    lc = ws.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).column '' Get the last column again for the While loop
Wend

End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Will your column headers be consistent throughout the sheet? At least for the two columns you want to keep pairwise.

Comment: @Lowpar Yes, the first column calls "Attribute" and the second "Category" for each pair

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit inefficient because I am out of the office. It should work, but if there are missing columns this will be problematic, because of the pairwise and lack of knowledge as to what the other columns could be.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveColumnsUnderAB()
Dim y, store, lc
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

lc = ws.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column '' Find the last column
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, lc))

For Each y In rng

If y = "Attribute" Or y = "Category" Or IsEmpty(y.Offset(1, 0)) And y.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown).Row > ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row Then
Else
store = Left(y.Address, InStr(2, y.Address, "$") - 1)
store = Right(store, InStr(1, y.Address, "$"))
ws.Range(store & "2:" & store & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 1)).Select
Selection.Cut
ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately the code does not work for my data or my simple example that I described above. It is weird, but I do not get any error message.